# Weird Instagram API limits for live app? Not letting users follow/unfollow?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have a live, approved Instagram stats app. A number of users have been reporting to me that the app will randomly stop letting them follow/unfollow users. I know for a fact that my code is correct as thousands of people have been using it for months.

The issue is related to Instagram. Here is how it happens:

A user who has been using my app will open it for the first time in 24 hours. Because they haven't used it in 24 hours, there should theoretically not be any limit. They try to follow/unfollow someone--it will fail.

I have all the approved permissions, I assure you. This issue is affecting a subset of my users--it seems like they are power users who follow/unfollow hundreds of accounts per day.

I'm guessing that Instagram is clandestinely trying to limit how many follow/unfollows a user can make per day. Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Instagram API limits how many times users can follow/unfollow other users as documented [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/). Are you sure your power users are not hitting these limits?

Comment: They report to me that it happens even if they haven't used the app in the past few hours